# trailing constraint for subview added to main view is not sticking

Tags: ios, autolayout, gradient

I have a view with leading and trailing constraints constants = 20 to the superview. I'm trying to add a gradient layer to that view but it only draws a width of 560 which is the width in the storyboard (size classes active)

It seems like the trailing constraint isn't sticking as the view frame size is 768 as it should be for iPad. I'm getting no auto layout errors either and when I set the background color to something other than clear, it looks fine yet the gradient is still not drawn completely.

any ideas??

```
func setupGradient(view: UIView) {
    let colorArray = [UIColor.blackColor().CGColor, UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor]
    let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

    gradient.frame = view.bounds
    print(gradient.frame)
    print(self.view.bounds)
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
    gradient.colors = colorArray
    view.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
}
```

from print statement:
(0.0, 0.0, 560.0, 70.0)
(0.0, 0.0, 768.0, 1024.0)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Autolayout and autoresizing masks work on `UIViews` not on `CALayers`.

Once a layers frame is set autolayout can change the views frame but not Layers frame.

We need to change the layer frames manually

```
- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews {
  [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
  gradientLayer.frame = gradientView.bounds;
}
```